# Magento 2.2.2 - Remove default welcome message and show username post login

Tags: magento2, layout, customer, xml, header

I need to remove default welcome message from header but display username after successful login. Tried below to hide welcome message but it also removes username
after login

```
<referenceBlock name="header">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">other</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Also tried below

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
   <referenceBlock name="header" remove="true"/>  
</referenceBlock>
```

How do I achieve above using xml and without overriding template file ?

Answer (score 3):

1. On the Admin menu, go Content > Design > Configuration > Select
   your current theme > .
2. Choose the storeview you want to remove the welcome message.
3. Under Action column, open the Edit mode. Scroll down and expand
   the Header section.
4. Then, remove the Welcome Text.

Comment: It takes default value `Default welcome msg!` if left empty

Comment: Worked on my installation, Magento 2.3.2, was fine to leave empty